# Bring a post to the top of the query if it's in a certain category?

Tags: wp-query, query

I'm looking for a way to bring a post if it's in a certain category to the front (or top) of the list. The category is called 'first'. I don't think `orderby` supports category so what other options do I have? Should I create another query inside the first query?

Thanks,

Comment: Sticky posts? You can also rerun the loop

Comment: Don't want to do sticky posts as I want as little interaction with the admin menu as possible. Can you provide an example of rerunning the loop?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192232/31545). You can use `in_category()` to test for your specific category. With regards to sticky posts, you can set a post as sticky without admin interface.

Comment: Gregory, if you want all the posts from `first` category displayed first and followed by all the posts not in that category, [knif3r's answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231887/45169)  is what you are looking for, but that functionality is already provided out of the box by sticky posts. You don't need a category. If, however, you want a normal flow of WP posts and if on that particular page there is a post from `first` category to be displayed first, it's doable, but a bit more complicated, as you will have to apply a filter on the results of your query before running the loop.

Comment: This question has continued - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232029/merging-a-complex-query-with-post-rewind-and-splitting-posts-into-two-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use 2 queries, where in the first loop you should use:

```
$args = array(  
  "post_type" => "post",
  "post_status" => "publish",
  "orderby" => "date",
  "order" => "DESC",
  "posts_per_page" => 20,
  'post__in' => cat,
);
(The Query)
```

And in the second:

```
$args = array(  
  "post_type" => "post",
  "post_status" => "publish",
  "orderby" => "date",
  "order" => "DESC",
  "posts_per_page" => 20,
  'post__not_in' => cat,
);
(The Query)
```

This should work because the first loop will take only the posts from `cat` and the second loop all others, and the first loop will always stay on top, Altought I don't know if you won't have a problem with the paginations that way, you should also ensure that you  reset the post data with `wp_reset_query();` for example.

Comment: There is no reason to use two queries

Comment: He wants all posts from `cat` to be displayed before other posts, for me the best way is to use 2 queries or sticky posts.