# Split loop into two columns, how to favor one side over the other

Tags: php, loop

I was able to divide posts into two columns but I have a problem if the loop has an odd number of posts. If the loop has an odd number of posts, like 9, the right side has the most posts than the left side. What I want is if the loop has an odd number of posts, they favor the left side instead of the right side.

For example: this is what the loop outputs if it has 7 posts:

`Post left | Post right`
`Post left | Post right`
`Post left | Post right`
`Post left | ----------`

What I'm trying to accomplish:

`Post left | Post right`
`Post left | Post right`
`Post left | Post right`
`--------- | Post right`

The code used to split the loop:

```
<?php $row_start = 1; while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
<?php if( in_array( get_the_ID(), $duplicates ) ) continue; ?>

<?php if( $row_start % 2 != 0) { ?>
<?php $left[] = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php $right[] = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php ++$row_start; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using css [last child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) . Just add float right to last child!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition for populating the `left` array. First set the number of posts into a variable lets say `$count` and then use the below condition

`if( $row_start % 2 != 0 && $row_start != $count )`

This skips populating the left array for the last element.

Comment: Got it working: `<?php if(in_array( get_the_ID(), $duplicates ) ) continue; ?>
    <?php if($row_start % 2 != 0 && $row_start != ($sum_total = $wp_query->found_posts - count($duplicates))):?>
     <?php $left[] = get_the_ID();?>
    <?php else:?>
     <?php $right[] = get_the_ID();?>
    <?php endif;?>`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to complete my task with your help - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233419/8049